# Is it possible to differentiate between front and back camera using CameraCharacterstics object

Tags: android, android-camera2

How to identify that the `CameraDevice` is front or back. Now I'am trying to find some field that could differentiate between front and back camera in `CameraCharacteristics`. Is this the right way? I don't want to open and switch between `CameraDevices` before knowing which one is right.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            try {
                cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
                String[] cameraList = cameraManager.getCameraIdList();
                for (String cameraId : cameraList) {
                    CameraCharacteristics cameraProps = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                    // Help here
                }
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    // Todo
                }
            } catch (CameraAccessException cameraAccessException) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CameraCharacteristics has an integer variable named LENS_FACING which gives the direction the camera faces relative to device screen.

See official documentation here - 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_FACING